# Using Windows device driver on x86_64 Linux

Tags: linux, windows, drivers

Is there some generalized way for Linux to use, for devices that do not have drivers, the binary of the corresponding driver for Windows?

Probably something windows system emulation in any level.

I am especially interested in the scanner issue as SANE does not have a driver for my scanner.

Answer (score 1):

No. A general Windows driver emulator does not exist and would be *very* hard to create. You’d have to recreate the entirety of the kernel driver interfaces, much like Wine does with the userspace interface. A monumental undertaking.

Furthermore, there may be conceptional mismatches between how stuff works on Windows and Linux. Scanner drivers on Windows for example often conform to the TWAIN or WIA interface, both of which may be difficult to use with Linux and would have to be adapted.

A minimal implementation exists: [NDISwrapper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NDISwrapper), which was made for using Windows Wi-Fi drivers on Linux. NDISwrapper is very outdated (not compatible with newer kernel driver interfaces) though.

Your best bet is to just use a virtual machine with Windows to scan stuff.